# When I updated my Android Studio, I get a string array not being able to be resolved error

Tags: android

I used Array Adapter:

`adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.intents,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);`

And I used string-array like below:

```
<resources>  
    <string-array name="intents">  
        <item>Open Browser</item>  
        <item>Call Someone</item>  
        <item>Dial</item>  
        <item>Show Map</item>  
        <item>Search on Map</item>  
        <item>Take Picture</item>  
        <item>Show Contacts</item>  
        <item>Edit first contact</item>  
    </string-array>  
    <string name="app_name">xxx</string>  
</resources>
```

but the array is not able to be resolved.

Comment: `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.intents, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);`

Comment: Clean-Rebuild-Run